# How create groups in models in angular for filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How create groups in angular for filter? for example:

In my JSON I have this values for state orders :

1. pending
2. handling
3. invoiced
4. canceled
5. factured

If I will group it in pairs for example: 
pending + handling ==> pending only
invoid + factured == only invoice

I reduce state. 
Now in Angular, I have

```
select(ng-model="status")
    option(value='') Status
    option(value='{{ dataStatus.option1 }}') Pending
    option(value='{{ dataStatus.option2 }}') Factured
    option(value='{{ dataStatus.option3 }}') Canceled
```

In my json initial i have this:

```
$scope.dataStatus ={
        option1 : 'payment-pending',
        option2 : 'invoiced',
        option3 : 'canceled'
}
```

In my repeat i have this:

```
.pedidos-container-ordergroup( ng-repeat="order in orders  | filter:     status ")
```

I would like group this "order state" only in the view. My filter have received the same parameter(don't group)